# View-specific DNS forwarding?

Tags: dns, bind

I'm setting up a server which, as one of its roles, will be acting as a gateway for guest wifi. I want to set up BIND so that queries coming from the main network will be normally resolved but if the query comes from the guest subnet, it's forwarded to an external DNS provider which provides content-filtering.

If I configure a view for the guest subnet, can I tell it to forward all queries? I know you can set up forwarding on a system-wide basis but only want it for the one view..

Answer (score 1):

Ah, answered my own question.. the 'forwarders' option is valid within a view. Must remember to research properly before posting questions..